# Mathematica User Interface Tutorial

Tags: interface

There I am looking for Mathematica User Interface Tutorial if anyone know Please provide the Link or description UserInface like Importing file using Buttons poping dialog boxes etc. Any help will be appriciated

Comment: [1](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/interactive-usage/), [2](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NotebookBasics.html). Or just use the help button/menu and a little bit of searching.

Comment: The best learning resource IMHO is examining the workings of the CDF examples. However doing that is not something for new or inexperienced users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to deal with Mathematicas opportunities. Best is hit F1 and read the Documentation. You'll find "[Custom Interface Construction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CustomInterfaceConstruction.html)" with many Examples:

```
Button["Click Here", Print[10!]]
```

[image]

Or the "[GUIKit Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/GUIKit/guide/GUIKitPackage.html)" as well:

```
Needs["GUIKit`"]
ref = GUIRun["Wolfram/Example/Calculator"]
```

[image]

Concerning Import/Export read the Docu "[Importing and Exporting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html)":

```
s = Import["ExampleData/population.xls"]
```

> {{{1.31397*10^9, "China"}, {1.09535*10^9, "India"}, {2.98444*10^8,
>   "United States"}, {2.45453*10^8, "Indonesia"}, {1.88078*10^8,
>   "Brazil"}, {1.65804*10^8, "Pakistan"}, {1.47365*10^8,
>   "Bangladesh"}, {1.42894*10^8, "Russia"}, {1.3186*10^8,     "Nigeria"},
>   {1.27464*10^8, "Japan"}}}

```
Grid[s[[1]], Frame -> All]
```

[image]